# вычислить высоту cardView в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, cardview

Как правильно определить высоту CardView в одном item-е у RecyclerView?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру, вот мой код. Он практически работает, проблема в том, из 7 раз вызова onCreateViewHolder - только 6 раз нормально определяется высота, а первый раз пишет что объект у которого я хочу найти высоту == null.
P/S проблема в закоменченом коде...

Код адаптера:

```
class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var maxColumnHeight: Int = 543
    private var maxStepsValue: Long = 0
    var list: List<Pair<Int, WorkoutJournalItem>> = mutableListOf()

    //==============================================================================================

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_statistics_item, parent, false)

//        try {
//            val column = parent.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.statistics_item_column)
//            val columnHeight = column.measuredHeight
//            Log.d("ml", columnHeight.toString())
//
//        } catch (t: Throwable){
//            Log.d("ml", t.message)
//        }

        return StepsHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d("ml", holder.itemView.height.toString())

        val current = list[position]
        (holder as StepsHolder).bind(current)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    fun setData(list: List<Pair<Int, WorkoutJournalItem>>) {
        this.list = list

        // поиск max-значения шагов
        val itemWithMaxValue = list.maxBy { it.second.steps }
        maxStepsValue = itemWithMaxValue?.second?.steps?.toLong() ?: 0

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private inner class StepsHolder(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        private val column = item.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.statistics_item_column)
        private val tv_date = item.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.statistics_item_tv)

        fun bind(current: Pair<Int, WorkoutJournalItem>) {
            tv_date.text = DRY.getDateFromTimestamp(current.first.toString())
        }
    }

    private fun calcColumnHeight(item: WorkoutJournalItem): Int {
        return ((maxColumnHeight * item.steps) / maxStepsValue).toInt()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если 6ть раз работает гуд, то это означает что вы столкнулись с тем самым null - ом и его реально не существует. Да и вообще я сомниваюсь что  он у вас правильно меряет ведь вы пытаетесь мерять там где будет создан контейнер (и он ещё не создан, значит вы во втором+ разе меряеете предыдущий контейнер). Bам нужно перенести ваш код в конец метода onBindView(), когда все элементы будут уже созданы и мерять примерно так:

```
holder.getParent().getMeasuredHeight()
```

Но тут нужно учитывать, он померяет размер тот что есть на экране или тот что будет после обновления.

P.S. Это мои мысли по эому поводу. Возможно есть более подходящий метод для этой задачи.